# Script to enable Restore Points for all the users in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, shell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have windows server 2012 R2. I have around 200 users connected with Active Directory. I want to activate the System Restore Point for all the users by using GPOs at Active Directory.

I created the below script and assigned at the GPO:

```
Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Scripts -> Shutdown
```

... but it is not working. The commands run locally (shown below) do work correct from PowerShell.

What else I should configure, so this script will be applied to all the users on Active Directory?

Is enough this script to enable Restore points for all the computers in my environment?  I tried locally this commands in PowerShell and it is working correctly.

```
# enable system restore
Enable-ComputerRestore -Drive "C:\" , "D:\"
# create a checkpoint with current date as description
Checkpoint-Computer -Description "$(get-date)"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are enabling this at the forest/domain level GPO, right?
Why are you doing this setting here:

> Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Scripts -> Shutdown

You need to ensure that this setting here, is in place on all systems:

> Computer configuration/Administrative Templates/System/System Restore

It runs locally because interactively ran it and you have the permission to do so. So, for others, you set your script to either execute via a scheduled task at logon running only once, or use the script in a Run Once registry entry.